# Which Simulation environment can be used for DJI M210

Tags: dji-sdk

I am working on ROS OSDK for designing some algorithms to implement on M210 V2, but I want to check these algorithms in a simulation environment before deploying on the real hardware. Which simulation environment supports DJI M210? so i can run these in the simulation environment.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using the osdk video feed from the m210. then the USB port from 210 is still available for use with DJI assistant 2 simulations. In this simulation, you can only test the controller control damping frequency etc, can not be used for external feedbacks. But it is sufficient for carry out live tests if the control is stable.

The other option is to use airsim (Unreal engine 4 with ROS) to simulate the m210 response. This requires you to have GPU and install a lot of things. And you can only simulate on the provided platform. For dji platform, you have to implement it in an unreal studio. it takes time but can give you a vivid simulation results.